# XFCE on Debian: hiding block devices

Tags: debian, xfce, udev

I'm running XFCE 4.8 on Debian Wheezy, and I can't find a clean way to hide a block device (system's SATA/SSD drive) on the desktop but still be able to see `/` mount removable devices via Thunar. The latter means I'm aware of the "Removable Devices" on the Desktop Properties menu.

My root filesystem is mounted from `/dev/sda1`; but for an unknown reason, the device appears as unmounted on the desktop. The corresponding line on the `/etc/fstab` file is:

```
UUID=6afe1aa9-1768-47ed-0d4b-b030f0318766 / ext4 defaults,commit=600,noatime,discard,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Before using the disk's UUID, it was simply declared as `sda1`; and I had the same result.

Reading all the answers all around the web, these are the 2 options widely used :

```
$ pwd
/etc/udev/rules.d
$ cat 99-hide-partitions.rules # with udisks1
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1
```

or

```
$ cat 99-hide-partitions.rules # with udisks2
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

Then make `udev` refresh its rules by running `# udevadm trigger`.

Unfortunately, none of those makes the device disappear from the desktop. Of course, I already tried rebooting. The `udev` properties are taken into account as shows the following command:

```
sudo udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/sda1|grep HIDE  
E: UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE=1
```

`UDISKS_IGNORE` has no effect in this context as Debian wheezy is shipped with `udisks` v1 which still supports `UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE`.

Am I hitting an XFCE/Thunar bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have successfully upgraded my debian wheezy workstation to debian jessie (painless) and that bug does not exist anymore. No need for `udev` special rules, the system disk is not shown anymore

Answer (score 1):

The use of `UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE` appears to have been deprecated:

```
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
KERNEL=="sda2", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

At least for Ubuntu 12.10+, the lines above don't work anymore, and should be changed in something like this:

```
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
KERNEL=="sdb2", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

#### References

- [How to hide an NTFS partition from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu)

Comment: As I said, I already tried `UDISKS_IGNORE` and it doesn't make the device disappear either, but anyway, Debian wheezy still ships with `udisks` v1 which still supports `UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this changed since then, but I found out recently that in XFCE, a separate tool is used to manage disks; I don't know offhand if it is backed by udisk, but at any rate it uses a different flag that is expected to be in fstab... so I'm not sure why it would show up if you already have a line in fstab -- I guess that's changed since then.

So for everyone else:

Either: run the "Disks" utility (under Accessories) and locate the partition/disk in question then set the appropriate options under Edit Mount Options (a bit confusing when you're trying to hide it, I know),

Or: Add a line for that partition in your fstab and make sure it does **not** have x-gvfs-show as a flag.